# What are the faults of using Inheritance Inversion HoC pattern in React

Tags: reactjs, higher-order-components

I'm particularly interested in using Inheritance Inversion when doing conditional rendering in React, thanks to the accessibility of parent component via `this`.

Say I have a `withLabel` HOC, that takes an `Input` component and wrap a label outside of it, if the label is provided. So the API would look something like this:

```
const TextInputWithLabel = withLabel(TextInput)
<TextInputWithLabel label="foo" id="bar"/>
<TextInputWithLabel />
```

that respectively returns

```
 <label htmlFor="bar">
     foo
     <input type="text" id="bar"/>
 </label>
```

and

```
<input type="text"/>
```

While I've heard some people don't like it, they couldn't give me compelling reason.

Do you have any reasons against using II in a medium/large React code base? I'm looking for example where using II is not needed, or an explaination of why I should not use II in this particular case.

Comment: My only problem with it is the fact you're using IDs which hurts component reuse. Also, a fair assumption for he enduser is that they provide a label so you shouldn't need to cover the no-label case (maybe use PropTypes or TS depending on your situation) as to maintain expected behavior.

Comment: using ID is actually what make label works. You can see more at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label

Comment: @ctn Then allow to pass it in as a prop.

Comment: yes I actually did that. Sorry for the confusion, editing question rn.